# Implementing drag and drop in wp8.1

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, windows-8.1

I am trying to implement a drag and drop mechanism in a wp8.1 app. I was trying the ManipulationDelta event for that but, then stumbled upon the DragEnter and Drop event. I tried it with the following xaml code but the DragEnter event handler isn't being invoked. What is the correct way to do this? I couldn't find much information about it on the net.

```
<Rectangle Height="50" Width="50" Fill="#FF5D1111"
               x:Name="rectangle"
               AllowDrop="True"
               DragEnter="rectangle_DragEnter"></Rectangle>
```

Answer (score 1):

There's a bit more involved in hooking up drag and drop. The DragEnter event will not fire simply because another element is dragged over it using a transform.

A drag (and drop) operation is initiated by calling DragDrop.DoDragDrop(...), typically within a MouseMove event.

Drag and Drop takes a few steps to setup, and can seem quite daunting for something that should be so simple. There are some good tutorials out there. [This post explains](http://wpftutorial.net/DragAndDrop.html) the process with the minimum fuss :)

UPDATE: This solution is for WPF/Desktop apps. Windows Phone doesn't implement DragDrop in this way.

Comment: I looked at the post. The problem is that wp8.1 does not seem to contain the DragDrop class. Yet it has all the Drag Drop based events. Does wp8.1 support it even?

Comment: Ah, sorry @sauravdebp - I didn't realise you were on WP - I assumed we were talking WPF. I'm not sure WP implements drag and drop in that way.